# Can every positive real be written as the sum of a subsequence of dot dot dot

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I answered this thing [Infinite sum of prime reciprocals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840159/infinite-sum-of-prime-reciprocals/840161#840161) and now wonder what happens if we do not have such a strong condition as Bertrand's postulate. i have been fiddling with this, not sure either way.

Given a sequence $a_1 > a_2 > a_3 \cdots$ of strictly decreasing positive reals such that
$$ a_i \rightarrow 0 \; \; \; \mbox{but} \; \; \sum a_i = \infty,  $$
can every positive real number be expressed as the sum of a subsequence of the $a_i?$ The main thing is that we are **not** given any upper bound on $a_n / a_{n+1}.$ For the reciprocals of the primes, we had an upper bound of $2.$

Note that this is subtler than the thing about rearranging a strictly alternating conditionally convergent series to get anything you specify. That is a matter of overshooting with positive terms, then undershooting with negative terms, back and forth. This one is a little different.

I think what I want is a careful proof of this: given two positive real numbers $B<C,$ we can find a finite subsequence of the $a_n$ with sum between $B$ and $C.$

Comment: The upper bound won't matter.  $\sum_{i\geq N} a_i = \infty$ also, so any large gap (large $a_n/a_{n+1}$) can be overcome by just accumulating some subsequence of the remaining tail.

Comment: @Eric, I dunno.

Comment: Wouldn't the greedy algorithm of selecting the lowest index term that doesn't overshoot work?

Comment: Here is an algorithmic stab at the problem:

Let $ r $ be a positive real number. Set $ S = 0 $ and $ n = 1 $.

If $ S + a_{n} < r $, then redefine $ S \mapsto S + a_{n} $, redefine $ n \mapsto n + 1 $ and resume.

If $ S = r $, then STOP.

If $ S > r $, then redefine $ n \mapsto n + 1 $ and resume.

If the algorithm does not terminate, then $ S $ is an infinite sum converging to $ r $ whose terms are a subsequence of $ (a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I thought so when I first answered the prime thing, gradually the bound given by Bertrand came to seem more and more necessary. It became a peculiar mixed strategy

Comment: @WillJagy:  What Bertrand gave you was quadratic convergence.  The conditions above are too loose to give such a strong result, but they are strong enough to (2) reach up to any positive number and (1) approach it as finely as you like (where the numbering matches the order of your hypotheses).

Comment: Don't really need careful, it is so clear it barely requires proof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x$ be our target sum. Pick an $i$ such that $a_k < x/2$ for all $k \ge i$. Take elements from the sequence starting at $a_i$ until their sum is greater than $x/2$. We can't overshoot $x$ (because the terms we're looking at are less than $x/2$), and we're guaranteed to have enough elements of enough magnitude to reach $x/2$. Repeat the procedure with a target of $x-whateversumwegot$ and keep repeating to build a subsequence with a sum of $x$.

Comment: Good. i understand this. Just leave the greedy idea out of things.

Comment: Why do you restrict $i$ so that  $a_k < x/2$ for all $k \ge i$...? IMHO _any_ $a_i \lt x$ will do as the first term as well, not necessarily $a_i < x/2$. Actually $a_i = x$ will do, too, just making the subsequence finite (single-term, to be precise).

Comment: @CiaPan: That'd work too. It'd just require a few minor adjustments to the logic.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ be the desired real number, and let $i_1$ be the smallest positive integer such that $x > a_{i_1}$ (we know such an integer exists because $a_i \to 0$). Now let $i_2$ be the smallest positive integer greater than $i_1$ such that $x - a_{i_1} > a_{i_2}$. Continuing in this way, we obtain a subsequence $(a_{i_j})_{j=1}^{\infty}$ and the sequence of partial sums $(S_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is strictly increasing and is bounded above by $x$, so $S_k \to y \leq x$.

Suppose $y < x$ and set $\varepsilon = x - y$. Let $N$ be the smallest positive integer such that $a_N < \varepsilon$ and let $J$ be the largest positive integer such that $i_J < N$ (so $N \leq i_{J+1}$). As $i_{J+1}$ is the smallest positive integer greater than $i_J$ such that $x - a_{i_1} - \dots - a_{i_J} > a_{i_{J+1}}$ and $x - a_{i_1} - \dots - a_{i_J} > x - y = \varepsilon > a_N$, we must have $N = i_{J+1}$. Now note that $x - a_{i_1} - \dots - a_{i_J} - a_{i_{J+1}} > x - y = \varepsilon$, so $i_{J+2} = N+1$, and likewise $i_{J+M} = N+M-1$. But then

$$y = \lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^ka_{i_j} = \sum_{j=1}^Ja_{i_j} + \lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{j=J+1}^ka_{i_j} = \sum_{j=1}^Ja_{i_j} + \lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=N}^ka_i$$

which is a contradiction as the series diverges (because $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i = \infty$).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say certainly so. Denote $S_{n,m} = \sum_{i=n}^m a_i$. Fix $L \in \mathbb{R}_+$ the desired limit. Set $R_0 = L$. Given $R_i$ for $i \geq 0$ first pick $N_i$ the least integer with $a_{N_i} < R_i$, and $M_i$ to be the minimal integer $M_i \geq N_i$ with $S_{N_i,M_i} < R_i < S_{N_i,M_i + 1}$. Then set $R_{i+1} = R_i - S_{N_i,M_i}$. Note that $N_{i+1} > M_i$, and that $L = \sum_i S_{N_i,M_i}$. Obviously there's a bit of verification.

On a philosophical level this is very similar to the alternating case, however here we don't allow overshoot as we have culling rather than negative terms.

Answer (score 1):

The key is that the conditions guarantee that, given $\varepsilon>0$, we can find a subsequence $\{b_n\}$ with $0<b_n<\varepsilon$ and $\sum b_n=\infty$.

So, given $r>0$, choose $a_{n_1},\ldots,a_{n_{k_1}}$ with $0<a_{n_j}<1/2$ and $$r-1/2\leq a_{n_1}+\cdots+a_{n_{k_1}}<r.$$

Next we choose $a_{n_k+1},\ldots,a_{n_{k_2}}$ with $0<a_{n_j}<1/3$ and
$$r-1/3\leq a_{n_1}+\cdots+a_{n_{k_2}}<r$$
(maybe none are needed). Repeating this, we eventually will have $a_{n_1},\ldots,a_{n_{k_m}}$ such that 
$$
r-1/m<a_{n_1}+\cdots a_{n_{k_m}}<r.
$$